# How to get the path to a Go module dependency?

Tags: go, code-generation, go-modules

I have two Go modules, let's name them `example.com/a` and `example.com/b`.

Let this be `example.com/a`'s `go.mod`:

```
module example.com/a

go 1.12

require (
  example.com/b v0.4.2
)
```

In `example.com/b`'s root directory, there is a file named `data.yaml`. `example.com/a` needs to autogenerate some code as part of its build process. This autogeneration needs to read `data.yaml`.

How can I in the directory of `example.com/a` query for the path of `example.com/b` to read that file? I know that after downloading, the module will be *somewhere* in `(go env GOPATH)/pkg/mod` but I don't know how the path will be constructed from there as it contains some `!` characters that are not part of the import path. I hoped that there is some subcommand of `go mod` or `go list` that will output the path, but I haven't found it in the documentation.

I have thought about including `data.yaml` in Go code via `go-bindata` (yes I'm aware of `//go:embed` but I don't want to require Go 1.16 for now) but then I would only have access at run-time when I need it at compile-time.

Comment: Not sure if you considered this option but, you could have `example.com/b` export a function which uses `runtime.Caller` to figure out its file's location and using that constructs the absolute path to the yaml file and returns it. Then the `example.com/a` could invoke this function to get that location. I do use this approach myself where `a` imports `b`, `a` invokes a function of `b`, that function reads css/js/html files from its own module's folder hierarchy and then writes copies of those files into `a`.

Comment: @mkopriva Interesting idea, but still a run-time solution. The code generator runs before I have anything compiled and linked against `example.com/b` so I can't call a function from there.

Comment: *"but I don't know how the path will be constructed from there as it contains some ! characters that are not part of the import path."* -- See the paragraph just above the table [here](https://golang.org/ref/mod#goproxy-protocol): *"To avoid ambiguity when serving from case-insensitive file systems, the $module and $version elements are case-encoded by replacing every uppercase letter with an exclamation mark followed by the corresponding lower-case letter. This allows modules example.com/M and example.com/m to both be stored on disk, since the former is encoded as example.com/!m."*

Comment: On my system that turns the package `github.com/BurntSushi/toml` dir location into `/Users/mkopriva/Work/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!burnt!sushi/toml@v0.3.1` -- so maybe you can use that rule to make sure to find the package in the correct place.

Comment: Also, if your generator is written in Go, and you're ok with modifying it for this purpose, you could use the package golang.org/x/tools/go/packages to load a package with the `packages.NeedModule` flag, which will load info on the package's module, including it's directory, if there is any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `go list` with the `-m` flag and the `-f` flag like so:

```golang
go list -m -f '{{.Dir}}' example.com/b
```

The `-m` flag:

> causes go list to list modules instead of packages. In this mode, the
> arguments to go list may be modules, module patterns (containing the
> ... wildcard), version queries, or the special pattern all, which
> matches all modules in the build list. If no arguments are specified,
> the main module is listed.

([reference](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-list-m))

The `-f` flag:

> specifies an alternate format for the output, using the syntax of
> package template. The struct being passed to the template, when using
> the `-m` flag, is:
>
> ```golang
> type Module struct {
>     Path      string       // module path
>     Version   string       // module version
>     Versions  []string     // available module versions (with -versions)
>     Replace   *Module      // replaced by this module
>     Time      *time.Time   // time version was created
>     Update    *Module      // available update, if any (with -u)
>     Main      bool         // is this the main module?
>     Indirect  bool         // is this module only an indirect dependency of main module?
>     Dir       string       // directory holding files for this module, if any
>     GoMod     string       // path to go.mod file for this module, if any
>     GoVersion string       // go version used in module
>     Error     *ModuleError // error loading module }
>
> type ModuleError struct {
>     Err string // the error itself
> }
> ```

<sup>[the above quote was altered for context]</sup>

([reference](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-List_packages_or_modules))

Comment: Though the `packages.NeedModule` solution would also be viable, this is certainly the easier solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can figure out the module path like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path"

    "golang.org/x/mod/module"
)

func GetModulePath(name, version string) (string, error) {
    // first we need GOMODCACHE
    cache, ok := os.LookupEnv("GOMODCACHE")
    if !ok {
        cache = path.Join(os.Getenv("GOPATH"), "pkg", "mod")
    }

    // then we need to escape path
    escapedPath, err := module.EscapePath(name)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // version also
    escapedVersion, err := module.EscapeVersion(version)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return path.Join(cache, escapedPath+"@"+escapedVersion), nil
}

func main() {
    var path, err = GetModulePath("github.com/jakubDoka/mlok", "v0.4.7")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if _, err := os.Stat(path); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        fmt.Println("you don't have this module/version installed")
    }
    fmt.Println("module found in", path)
}
```

Comment: Good to know that the escaping routines used for creating the paths are exposed this way, thanks for showing that. I will go with mkopriva's solution since it automatically fetches the version number from `go.mod` which I would need to do manually here.